pointer to member function as template parameter issue
I want to be able to defer calls to member functions of some object. Therefore, I need to be able to store member function pointers plus parameters as data.
My approach uses C++ templates that treat the member function pointers as part of the type. The function pointer should be a template parameter, as I want to be able to select via static_assert at compile time, which member functions are allowed (ie. only setters);
I am using gcc (GCC) 14.1.1 20240507 and C++ 23.
Example Code:
struct Object {
    void set();
    void set(int test);
    int get();
};

// Utils:

template <typename Function>
struct FunctionTraits;

template <
    typename Return,
    typename... Args
> struct FunctionTraits
<Return (Object::*)(Args...)>
{
    using args_tuple_t = std::tuple<Args...>;
    using ret_t = Return;
};

// The member function wrapper:

template <
    typename Function,
    Function function
>
struct SetterTask
{
    Object* obj;
    typename FunctionTraits<decltype(function)>::args_tuple_t args;
};

// pseudo constructor

template <
    typename Return,
    typename... Args
>
auto makeSetter(
        Object* obj,
        Return (Object::*setter)(Args...),
        Args... args
)
{
    auto tuple = std::tuple( args... );
    using SetterType = Return (Object::*)(Args...);  // <-- ERROR
    return SetterTask<SetterType,setter>{            // <-- ERROR
        .obj = obj,
        .args = tuple
    };
}

template <
    typename Function,
    Function function
>
auto run(
        SetterTask<Function, function> setter
)
{
    return std::apply(setter.function,
            std::tuple_cat(
                std::make_tuple(setter.obj),
                setter.args
            )
    );
}

Test program:
void test() {
    void (Object::*pFunc)(int) = &Object::set;
    Object obj;
    auto setter = makeSetter( &obj, pFunc, 10 );
    run(setter);
}

This is the error I get:
template_test.cpp:10:26:   required from here
   10 |         auto setter = makeSetter( &obj, pFunc, 10 );
      |                       ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
template_test.h:61:9: error: ‘setter’ is not a valid template argument for type ‘void (Object::*)(int)’
   61 |         };
      |         ^
template_test.h:61:9: note: it must be a pointer-to-member of the form ‘&X::Y’

What am I doing wrong? To my understanding, the types are all clear, even overly explicit.
Or is this a compiler bug?
This is the critical section:
template <
    typename Return,
    typename... Args
>
auto makeSetter(
        Object* obj,
        Return (Object::*setter)(Args...),
        Args... args
)
{
    auto tuple = std::tuple( args... );
    using SetterType = Return (Object::*)(Args...);  // <-- ERROR
    return SetterTask<SetterType,setter>{            // <-- ERROR
        .obj = obj,
        .args = tuple
    };
}

I also tried:
    using SetterType = decltype(setter);  <-- decltype of pointer
    return SetterTask<SetterType,setter>{
            ...
    };

...and...
    using SetterType = Return (Object::*)(Args...);
    return SetterTask<SetterType,(SetterType)setter>{ <-- explicitly cast pointer
            ...
    };


Is there anything wrong with std::function?

Also, concerning the "plus parameters": std::function is pretty much the big thing that can store "anything" that remotely looks or smells like it's something that can be called. This includes objects created by the std::bind family, or lambda functions, as ways to attach data to the callables.

std::function is wonderful, but to permissive.
I want to use the type system to be able to assert at compile time, that only certain member functions to a specific object are valid.
Therefore, the function pointer should be part of the type.

In C++, a runtime value, in this case the function call argument setter: Return (Object::*setter)(Args...), cannot be used as template instantation argument. It does not only apply to pointers to members - it applies to all non-type, non-template template parameters (if nothing changes in C++23 in this area)...

"I want to use the type system to be able to assert at compile time, that only certain member functions to a specific object are valid." - use concepts?

@Den-Jason: Interesting. I haven't yet studied concepts. It's on my list.

As PiotrNycz correctly pointed out, a template "value" parameter cannot be set from a function argument, neither from any runtime value.
Quite obvious, if you think about it - template parameters are compile-time constants.
This is my solution:
template_test.h:
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>


struct Object {
    double set();
    void set(int test);
    void set2(int test);
    int get();
};

// Allowed member functions:

template <typename Function, Function function>
struct IsAllowedFunction : std::false_type {};

template <> struct IsAllowedFunction
<double (Object::*)(), (double (Object::*)())&Object::set>
: std::true_type {};

template <> struct IsAllowedFunction
<void (Object::*)(int), (void (Object::*)(int))&Object::set>
: std::true_type {};

template <> struct IsAllowedFunction
<void (Object::*)(int), (void (Object::*)(int))&Object::set2>
: std::true_type {};

// Utils:

template <typename Function>
struct FunctionTraits;

template <
    typename Return,
    typename... Args
> struct FunctionTraits
<Return (Object::*)(Args...)>
{
    // the tuple must be saved
    // as full values, not just
    // as reference:
    using args_tuple_t = std::tuple<std::remove_cvref_t<Args>...>;
    using ret_t = Return;
};

// The member function wrapper:

template <
    typename Function,
    Function function
>
struct SetterTask
{
    Object* obj;
    typename FunctionTraits<Function>::args_tuple_t args;
};

// pseudo constructor

template <
    typename Function,
    Function function,
    typename... Args
>
auto makeSetter(
        Object* obj,
        Args... args
)
{
    static_assert(
            IsAllowedFunction<Function,function>::value,
            "Invalid function. Valid functions functionare: 'set', 'set2'"
    );
    auto tuple = std::tuple( args... );
    return SetterTask<Function,function>{
        .obj = obj,
        .args = tuple
    };
}

template <
    typename Function,
    Function function
>
auto run(
        SetterTask<Function, function> setter
)
{
    return std::apply(
            function,
            std::tuple_cat(
                std::make_tuple(setter.obj),
                setter.args
            )
    );
}

#define MAKE_SETTER(obj, Type, Function, ... ) \
    makeSetter<Type, (Type )&Object::Function>( obj, ## __VA_ARGS__ )

main.cpp:
#include "template_test.h"
#include <iostream>


void test() {
    Object obj;
    // Example 1: `double set()`:
    {
        auto setter = MAKE_SETTER(&obj,double (Object::*)(),set);
        double ret = run(setter);
        std::cout << "function returned: " << ret;
    }
    // Example 2: `void set(int)`:
    {
        auto setter = MAKE_SETTER(&obj,void (Object::*)(int),set, 10);
        run(setter);
    }
    // Example 3: `void set(int)`:
    {
        auto setter = MAKE_SETTER(&obj,void (Object::*)(int),set2, 10);
        run(setter);
    }
    // the following is not allowed
    // and raises a compile-time error:
    // auto getter = MAKE_SETTER(&obj,double (Object::*)(),get);
}


